# XPath : Attribute Compare

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpathnavigator

I am looking for a solution to frame xpath logic to compare attributes.

```
<menucontainer id="menu1" op="o3" indicator="highlight">
<menubox>
<menutitle>TITLE</menutitle>
<menuoptionlist>
<menuoption id="o1">Select a path from below :</menuoption>
<menuoption id="o2">IMAGE1</menuoption>
<menuoption id="o3">IMAGE2</menuoption>
<menuoption id="o4">IMAGE3</menuoption>
<menuoption id="o5">IMAGE4</menuoption>
<menuoption id="o6">IMAGE5</menuoption>
</menuoptionlist>
</menubox>
</menucontainer>
```

Here I want to compare menucontainers op value (op="03") against the menuoption id's.So here the ideal match would be IMAGE2. And I would be highlighting the IMAGE2 in red colour.

I tried `//menublock/menucontainer/@op = //menublock/menucontainer/menuoptionlist/menuoption/@id`

but it is not dynamic.It checks first result and applies the same result everywhere.pls help in framing the xpath .

Comment: "*And I would be highlighting the IMAGE2 in red colour.*" Please post the expected result of the transformation.

Comment: Say for example , menucontainer/op = 03 = menucontainer/menubox/menuoptionlist/menuoption/id , So i must highligh IMAGE1 <IMAGE2>(RED BACKGROUND COLOR) IMAGE3 ..

Comment: Please edit your question and post (a) the stylesheet you have so far and (b) the expected result of the transformation **as code**.

Answer (score 0):

To return the node `menuoption` where the value is IMAGE2, based on the menuoption attribute `id` being equal to the menucontainer attribute `op` you can use the following XPath Selector
`//menucontainer/menubox/menuoptionlist/menuoption[@id=../../../@op]`

The `../` goes up a level. [W3schools XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

### [XPathFiddle](http://xpathfiddle.net/L9DV1R)

Comment: //menucontainer/menubox/menuoptionlist/menuoption[@id=../../../@op]  the issue with this is its not working when multiple menucontainers are available one below another.  Is it possible to provide xpath using preceing / following logic

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my crystal ball, i present you a solution.

**XPATH**: `//menuoption[@id = ancestor::menucontainer/@op]` [you can restrict the `//menuoption` as you want/needed.]

**XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="menuoption[@id = ancestor::menucontainer/@op]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <!-- add a specific attribute -->
            <xsl:attribute name="highlight">
                <xsl:text>red</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- identity copy -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Change the attribute `highlight` to whatever you want. Fit these templates in your environment. *[Crystal ball got a crack]*